# ng-grid example does not work on IE

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

The example "Edit On Focus Cell Selection Example" in ng-grid website works fine on Chrome, but it didn't work on IE 10 and 11, when i lost focus on the edit cell, the cell did not go back to readonly state.
Can anyone help and give me a better work round for it? 
Thanks in advance!

http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ng-grid has added an 'unselectable' attribute in the template, this attribute only works in IE, it will make the section unselectable.
The newly version ui-grid does not has it.
Just added some removing logic in the controller to remove it is ok.

```
//Remove unselectable attribute which is added by ngGrid
$timeout(function () {
    var ngViewPorts = angular.element.find('.ngViewport');
    angular.forEach(ngViewPorts, function(ngViewPort){
        if(ngViewPort.getAttribute('unselectable') === 'on') {
            ngViewPort.removeAttribute('unselectable');
        }
    });
});
```